# Stop "user agent stylesheet" in Chrome from making css look different between Windows and Linux

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm working on a webpage and have tested on both Windows and Linux. Everything renders correctly with Windows/Chrome and Linux/Firefox. But if I open the webpage using Linux/Chrome, an element I want hidden is incorrectly shown. Specifically, I have  `<div class="reveal">` and a .css file that includes:

```
.reveal {
  display: none;
}
```

But if I inspect the element while using Linux/Chrome, Dev Tools shows me:

```
div {                                          user agent stylesheet
  display: block;
}
```

And my `reveal` css class is not shown. What might be going on here and how can I fix the issue?

**edit:** changed the user agent stylesheet to reflect the proper `<div>` element.

Comment: User agent stylesheets are least specific. Issue is something else here

Comment: You won't see the reveal css, because you're inspecting its child element. It applies to parent div, but it should hide all child elements. Could you show your page/code?

Comment: @liroP The html or css or both? Both files are fairly long; what's the best way to do that?

Comment: I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h896jfx3/) for this, but I can't see anything wrong with Chrome/Linux.

Comment: Here's are links to the relevant full contexts:

https://github.com/Jessime/Excision/blob/master/src/templates/tutorial.html#L176

https://github.com/Jessime/Excision/blob/master/src/static/css/style_mdl.css#L118

Comment: There has to be more context to this problem.  Is that ALL the code, or is it part of a bigger picture? Try a deeper css selector, like div.reveal { display:none; }  ... or ... html body div.reveal { display:none; }

Comment: @JessimeKirk Can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I tested it with Ubuntu 17.04 and Chrome 58 and it works as expected.

Comment: I apologize everyone. This was an all-around poor question. I restarted my computer and things work properly now. What the proper course of action for shutting down this question?

Comment: @liroP Thanks for taking the time to testing it out.

Comment: @JessimeKirk If you want to delete the question, there is a `delete` link below it.